# Trying to autoscroll to the bottom of the screen within a timespan

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
        public void TimerScroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5), () =>
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                var lastChild = stkMain.Children.LastOrDefault();
                if(lastChild != null)
                    scrollView.ScrollToAsync(lastChild, ScrollToPosition.MakeVisible, true);
            });
            return true;
        });
    }
```

I am creating a teleprompter app and I am trying to get a my app to scroll through all of the text displayed through a label. Right now the button it is linked to is doing nothing.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView x:Name="scrollView">
        <AbsoluteLayout>
            <StackLayout x:Name="stkMain" BackgroundColor="Black" Padding="12" Margin="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label
                TextColor="#ffffff" 
                Text="{Binding MainPageEditorText}" 
                FontSize="{Binding MainPageSliderValue}" 
                ScaleX="-1.0"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="DarkGray" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="End"  HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                    <?Button x:Name="play_button" Clicked="TimerScroll" Text="Play" HorizontalOptions="Center"/?>
                    <Label Text="End"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
            <Button x:Name="play_button" Clicked="TimerScroll" Text="test" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".95,.95,80,80"/>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: What's the lastChild? Can you please share more code of your example? ScrollToAsync only scroll to the rect where lastChild is and it won't scroll through all of the text displayed in a label.

Comment: I added my xaml file.

Comment: I am pretty new to Xamarin so I would appreciate any help I could get.

Comment: @Superbia : Are you Looking for Like marquee(Where Text from Left to right Moving)? or you want to Move Whole Screen Contents.